# Is it possible to serve binary streams from a Relay server?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have seen a number of questions and answers regarding how to *upload* a file to a relay server, but I haven't found an example of how to serve one *from* a relay server.

I have seen examples [where there are URIs](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/ea03e9ba6bc5763c18b9745eeab375087507307e/docs/Guides-Containers.md) to binary resources, but nothing yet about whether relay itself can (or *should*) serve blobs, or whether I need to implement a parallel service.

Any advice, tutorials, examples, or counter-example would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I mean an app using the Facebook Relay implementation of GraphQL.